# Optimizing python code - searching within an unsorted list with nested loops as index positions need to be retained

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have a list (stockData) with some random positive integers
then another query list (queries) that contains some positions(indexes counted from 1 and not 0) within stockData.

Based on the 'queries', The code must identify a closest value smaller than the one at a give position. If there is a clash/tie, the smaller index position is preferred. If no such value can be identified on either side of position, then -1 should be returned.

Example1

```
stockData = [5,6,8,4,9,10,8,3,6,4]
queries = [6,5,4]

At position 6 (index=5) in stockData, value is 10, both position 5 (index=4) and position 7 (index=6) are smaller values (9 and 8 resp.) than 10, hence we choose the one at a lesser position -> [5]
At position 5 (index=4) in stockData, value is 9, position 4 (index=3) is smaller hence we choose position 4 -> [5,4]
At position 4 (index=3) in stockData, value is 4, position 8 (index=7) is only value smaller hence we choose position 8 -> [5,4,8]

Output
[5,4,8]
```

Example2

```
stockData = [5,6,8,4,9,10,8,3,6,4]
queries = [3,1,8]

Here, at position 8, the value 3 is the smallest of the list, so we return -1

Output
[2,4,-1]
```

Constraints

```
1 <= n <= 10^5 (n is the length of stockData)
1 <= stockData[i] <= 10^9 
1 <= q <= 10^5 (q is the length of queries)
1 <= queries[i] <= 10^9
```

My code is working fine, but taking too long to execute. Looking for any help with optimizing it or any other corrective measures. Thanks !!

My Code:

```
def predictAnswer(stockData, queries):
    # convert days to index
    query_idx = [val-1 for val in queries]

    # output_day_set
    out_day = []

    for day in query_idx:
        min_price = stockData[day]
        day_found = False
        
        for i in range(1, max(day,len(stockData)-day)):
            prev = day-i
            nxt = day+i
            if prev >= 0 and stockData[prev] < min_price:
                out_day.append(prev+1)                        
                day_found = True
                break
            if nxt < len(stockData) and stockData[nxt] < min_price:
                out_day.append(nxt+1)                        
                day_found = True
                break
        
        if not day_found:
            out_day.append(-1)
    
    return out_day
```

Solution Approach as suggested by @Carlos:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(stockData):
        if val in stockDict.keys():
            stockDict[val].append(idx)
        else:
            stockDict[val] = [idx]
    
    stockDict_sortedKeys = sorted(stockDict)
```

For the sample input:

```
stockData = [5,3,4,6,5,4,6,8,9,5,7]
```

Output:

```
stockDict = {5: [0], 6: [1, 8], 8: [2, 6], 4: [3, 9], 9: [4], 10: [5], 3: [7]}
stockDict_sortedKeys = [3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10]
```

Now may be for a for a given query 'day', I would need to find the corresponding sortedData[day] and find the closest index for all the values smaller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate on your `stockData` to get the most recent previous smaller value, by keeping a heap of local minima:

```
import heapq

class Data:
    def __init__(self, day, value):
        self.day = day
        self.value = value
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.value >= other.value
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Data(day={self.day}, value={self.value})'

def precalc(days):
    result = []
    heap = []
    for day, value in days:
        data = Data(day, value)
        while heap and heap[0] < data:
            heapq.heappop(heap)
        result.append(heap[0].day if heap else -1)
        heapq.heappush(heap, data)
    return result
```

The complexity is `O(n log(n))`, as each day can only be pushed/popped once.

To get the expected answer, you have to do it in the other direction also:

```
def compare(f, b, q):
    if f < 0: return b
    if b < 0: return f
    if q-f <= b-q:
        return f
    else:
        return b

def predictAnswer(stockData, queries):
    forward = precalc(enumerate(stockData, 1))
    backward = list(reversed(precalc(reversed(list(enumerate(stockData, 1))))))
    return [compare(forward[q-1], backward[q-1], q) for q in queries]
```

This is still `O(n log(n))`.

Comment: You can see it in action there:  https://repl.it/repls/GigaThinParallelport

Comment: This is the right answer, keeping a running min turns it into n log n.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Great learning. For some reason, the online testing interface still kept throwing execution timeout error but cant imagine that being an issue with this code as it  is working fine for me on VSCode locally.